# Matrix elements manipulation

Tags: r

```
b = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1)
c = c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,5)
a <- NULL
a  <- matrix(c(b,c), ncol=2)
```

What I want to do is to compare the numbers In the first column of this matrix, and if the first number is equal to the second consecutive number in the column (in this case if 1 = 1, and so on) then I want to add the corresponding numbers in the second column together (as in 10 + 10 = 20, and so on) and that would be only one value and I want then to store this output in a separate vector.

The output from the matrix I am looking for is as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]    1   10  20 
[2,]    1   10  40
[3,]    2   20  62
[4,]    2   20  85
[5,]    3   30  5
[6,]    3   32
[7,]    4   40
[8,]    4   45
[9,]    1   5
```

I am quite new to R and struggling with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: All columns in a matrix should have the same length. Wouldn't you rather store the values in a separate vector, or a matrix with two columns?

Comment: Not that it matters for the general problem to be solved (I believe), but please note that your vector `c` differs from column 2 in the output matrix.

Comment: Can you please explain the 5 in column 3 in the output matrix.

Comment: @ krlmlr. I would like just to store the output, it doesnt matter to me if its in the matrix or in a separate vector. The original vectors b = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1) and c = c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,5) are extracted from the separate lists. 

I just dont know how to manipulate these on the initial condition (if the consecutive vector elements in b are equal) then add the corresponding elements in the 2nd vector together. And store them in a new vector.

Comment: @Henrik, The 5 is just a number I've put in. The actual vectors are about 10000000 in length.

Comment: @Henrik, the pattern is very random, there is no recognised pattern in the vector (b). But based on the initial condition, that is when the two constitutive numbers are equal. I want to stop the loop and then add the corresponding numbers in the second vector together, subsequently storing the sum in a new vector. And I want to do this for all the numbers in the first vector

Comment: I asked about the 5 because I don't understand how this number can be explained from the rules for calculation you have described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `rle` and `tapply`:

```
b = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1)
c = c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,5)
a <- NULL
a  <- matrix(c(b,c), ncol=2)

A <- rle(a[, 1])$lengths
tapply(a[, 2], rep(seq_along(A), A), sum)
#  1  2  3  4  5 
# 20 40 60 80  5
```

Explanation:

- `rle` identifies the run-lengths of the items in the first column of matrix "a".
- We create a grouping variable for `tapply` from the run-lengths using `rep(seq_along(A), A)`.
- We put those two things together in `tapply` to get the sums you want.

Comment: Thx Amanda I appreciate your help, I initially was looping twice to do this (turning into long evaluation). Would u recommend any particular books for me to read I would greatly appreciate you're help

Comment: @user2753526, the ["info" page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) at [tag:r] includes many resources to get started.

Comment: @user2753526 if you greatly appreciate the help feel free to express it by either upvoting these useful answers and/or marking one of them as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to the most useful one (if they answer your question). (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? I bet there are clean `base` solutions, but I give it a try with `rollsum` in `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
mm <- cbind(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1), c(10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 5))

# calculate all lagged sums of column 2
sums <- rollsum(x = mm[ , 2], k = 2)

# calculate differences between consecutive numbers in column 1
diffs <- diff(mm[ , 1])

# select sums where diff is 0, i.e. where the two consecutive numbers in column 1 are equal.
sums2 <- sums[diffs == 0]

sums2
# [1] 20 40 60 80
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want, however I also need the last and the first number to compare to the next one, and If its not equal to it , store the corresponding number in the second vector on its own. so for the last "1" in the vector the corresponding value "5" will be stored in the vector too

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you need to update your question then. The 5 does not follow from your original description of the problem: "if the first number is equal to the second consecutive number in the column [...] then I want to add the corresponding numbers in the second column together"

Comment: Sorry I should have phrased the question properly. This works now I got the plot I wanted, cheers. 

Also Thank you everyone for your help, much appreciated. Hopefully soon I would be able to get on top of R and help you guys (highly unlikely as you're wizards).

Comment: Thank you very much Henrik, would you recommend further reading? Im using R for a bout a week now :(

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! Regarding further reading, the suggestion by @Ananda Mahto is an excellent start. You may also check [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/). Search [r-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/) for tons of tutorials. [This](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-79054-1/page/1) is a nice, freely available book.